# t.xpath not getting results from second page?

Tags: python, selenium, lxml

I am trying to iterate over multiple pages of a website, however the code I am using below is only returning the results from the first page, even though I am using Selenium to click to the next page. I am at a loss for what could be causing this. Any explanation would be much appreciated!

The website in question:
[https://www.cruiseplum.com/search#{%22numPax%22:2,%22geo%22:%22US%22,%22portsMatchAll%22:true,%22numOptionsShown%22:100,%22ppdIncludesTaxTips%22:true,%22uiVersion%22:%22split%22,%22sortTableByField%22:%22dd%22,%22sortTableOrderDesc%22:false,%22filter%22:null}](https://www.cruiseplum.com/search#%7B%22numPax%22:2,%22geo%22:%22US%22,%22portsMatchAll%22:true,%22numOptionsShown%22:100,%22ppdIncludesTaxTips%22:true,%22uiVersion%22:%22split%22,%22sortTableByField%22:%22dd%22,%22sortTableOrderDesc%22:false,%22filter%22:null%7D)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import xlsxwriter
from lxml import html

u = 'https://www.cruiseplum.com/search#{%22numPax%22:2,%22geo%22:%22US%22,%22portsMatchAll%22:true,%22numOptionsShown%22:100,%22ppdIncludesTaxTips%22:true,%22uiVersion%22:%22split%22,%22sortTableByField%22:%22dd%22,%22sortTableOrderDesc%22:false,%22filter%22:null}'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(u)
driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(.3)

driver.find_element_by_id('restoreSettingsYesEncl').click() # select 'yes' on the webpage to restore settings
time.sleep(7) # wait until the website downloads data so we get a return value

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
source_code = elem.get_attribute("innerHTML")

t = html.fromstring(source_code)

for i in range(5):

    for i in t.xpath('.//td[@class="dc-table-column _0"]/text()'):
        print(i.strip())

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="listings-table-split"]/div[5]/div/span[4]').click() # click to next page
    time.sleep(.05)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code above, t is getting value outside the loop

> elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*") source_code =
>   elem.get_attribute("innerHTML")
>
> t = html.fromstring(source_code)
>
> for i in range(5):

so it is loaded only the first time and keeps repeating the same elements. To achieve you need to move it inside the loop like in the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import xlsxwriter
from lxml import html

u = 'https://www.cruiseplum.com/search#{%22numPax%22:2,%22geo%22:%22US%22,%22portsMatchAll%22:true,%22numOptionsShown%22:100,%22ppdIncludesTaxTips%22:true,%22uiVersion%22:%22split%22,%22sortTableByField%22:%22dd%22,%22sortTableOrderDesc%22:false,%22filter%22:null}'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(u)
driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(.3)

driver.find_element_by_id('restoreSettingsYesEncl').click() # select 'yes' on the webpage to restore settings
time.sleep(7) # wait until the website downloads data so we get a return value



for i in range(5):
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
    source_code = elem.get_attribute("innerHTML")

    t = html.fromstring(source_code)
    for i in t.xpath('.//td[@class="dc-table-column _0"]/text()'):
        print(i.strip())

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="listings-table-split"]/div[5]/div/span[4]').click() # click to next page
    time.sleep(.05)

driver.quit()
```